# How come when I add xmlns to my doctype, the widths of my text boxes change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

When I added xmlns, the text boxes got shorter. It's screwing up all of my styles for my input boxes. Why?

Note: I see that in my developer console, this was added to the text boxes:

```
input:not([type="image"]), textarea {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

What is this and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To override what is being set:**

```
input:not([type="image"]), textarea {
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```

The default box-sizing property is `content-box`.  When you use the `xmlns`, some browsers might change the box model because it thinks it should.  That's probably a good thing.  For places it causes you problems, simply override their styles.

**Edit:** I just noticed what @Alohci did, that is, that you are putting the `xmlns` on the `doctype` tag instead of the `html` tag.  You can patch it if you'd like to, but I'd recommend moving the attribute to `html` and see if that keeps things the way they should be.

Answer (score 2):

The xmlns attributes go on the `<html>` start tag, not the doctype.

If, after `<DOCTYPE html` and white space, the next character is not `>` then the next six characters must be either `PUBLIC` or `SYSTEM` case-insensitive, or else the page will be processed in quirks mode. Your doctype is causing quirks mode. Take the xmlns attributes off, and the doctype will cause standards mode.

See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tokenization.html#after-doctype-name-state for details.

Answer (score 0):

The doctype tag tells the browser what kind of HTML you want to use. Each browser is going to have a default it uses when there is not one specified. The default display styles for different types of HTML content will differ. So when you specified the doc type you likely picked one that was different from the default one the browser was using.

Which will require you to specify some styles to ensure your document looks as you expect across all browsers.